# How to remove key+value pair from an object of Array

Tags: javascript

I want to remove property 'b' from all objects
how i remove???

```
 let result=[
    {
       'id':'1',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    {
       'id':'2',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    ...
    ,
    { 
       'id':'2000',
       'b':'asd'
    },
 ]  
  // delete object.b; its only for object and want to remove from whole 
   //  array 2000 records
```

Using foreach loop is it correct way to delete key + value pair from array of objects

Comment: `result = result.map( x => { delete x.b; return x } )`

Comment: @Tibrogargan, no, `map` creates a new array. You need to mutate the original one.

Comment: Yes, using foreach loop is it correct way

Comment: @MihaiAlexandru-Ionut Why?  The old one will get marked for deletion and the `result` variable will hold and new array with the same references

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if that one is the only structure you have you can do this

```
result = result.map(e => ({ id: e.id }))
```

or if the structure is far more complicated, you might want to use `delete`:

```
result.forEach((e) => {
    delete e.b;
});
```

Comment: Not what was asked.  You're assuming the only key in the members of `result` are `id` and `b`

Comment: edited to include the generic case

Answer (score 1):

You could use `forEach`.

```js
 let result=[
    {
       'id':'1',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    {
       'id':'2',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    { 
       'id':'2000',
       'b':'asd'
    },
 ];
result.forEach(function(item){ delete item.b });
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Why do you need jquery here ?

Comment: Thanks for reminding. It is habit :)

Answer (score 0):

Try following code:

```js
let result=[
    {
       'id':'1',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    {
       'id':'2',
       'b':'asd'
    },
    { 
       'id':'2000',
       'b':'asd'
    }
 ];
 
 for(let i in result){
    let obj = result[i];
    delete obj['b'];
 }
 console.log(result);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Yes it Helps me. But Is it right way to do that. because result contain 4000 records. so using it needs for loop and its run 4000 times