# reduce an array of objects in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

how can I reduce an array of objects of this type:

```
[
 {id: 1, name: 'jhon', lastname: 'doe', age: 30},
 {id: 2, name: 'max', lastname: 'wall', age: 20},
 {id: 3, name: 'fer', lastname: 'baneg', age: 15}
]
```

I need to get a new array just with these values:

```
[
 {id: 1, name: 'jhon'},
 {id: 2, name: 'max'},
 {id: 3, name: 'fer'}
]
```

Comment: Delete unnecessary properties, create new objects with only the relevant properties, ...

Comment: Exact Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48396052/how-to-remove-keyvalue-pair-from-an-object-of-array

Comment: unlucky use of "reduce" in question title

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `map()` method for this with ES6 parameter destructuring.

```js
const data = [{id: 1, name: 'jhon', lastname: 'doe', age: 30},{id: 2, name: 'max', lastname: 'wall', age: 20},{id: 3, name: 'fer', lastname: 'baneg', age: 15}]

const result = data.map(({id, name}) => ({id, name}))
console.log(result)
```